# Java DatagramSocket can't receive all packets

Tags: java, sockets, kotlin, datagram

i write a very simple kotlin program to receive image from client. the key part as follow.

```
      while (running) {
        try {
            buf = ByteArray(buffSize)
            packet = DatagramPacket(buf, buf.size)
            socket.receive(packet)
            // put packet data in blockingQueue, use thread to consume the queue
            queue.offer(arrayOf(buf.clone(), packet!!.address, packet!!.port, packet!!.length))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

when this program running surface pro, it can't receive all the packets client send to it. for example client send 1000 packets it receive 900 packets, then stuck at socket.receive(). the Wireshark running on the surface pro at the same time shows that all the 1000 packets is received.

when the program is running on a mac pro, it's just ok. no packet lost.

Answer (score 0):

after many tries, i find out when i changed the package platform the problem gone. so i guess the problem is caused by package tool (gradle with application plugin, Kotlin plugin ), or some unkown bugs of specific jdk version.